# Windows 7 64-bit showing 12GB (7.99GB usable)

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I've just added 2GB of Memory to my 10GB (4GBx2 + 2GBX2). They're all in their correct slot, and the 2GB's speed match.

I am now noticing that windows is showing "12.0GB (7.99GB usable)". I checked the performance tab in task manager and it seems like the Available and Free memory counters roughly add up to 12GB.

Is it just windows not showing the correct number?

Comment: It might be a limit of the motherboard, check it's documentation.

Comment: Check with Resource Monitor.

Comment: @ZippyV, it's not the motherboard, checked that before doing what I mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: For an explanation of Task Manager Performance tab see http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2013/05/03/finally-a-windows-task-manager-performance-tab-blog.aspx . Available = Free + Standby, adding them together is meaningless.

Comment: I checked again after it worked, and realised this. So it was actually not being used and not a case of windows not showing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like an idiot.

I decided to remove it and attach it again, making sure that it's pushed in well. And it's ok now.

Not sure why it was recognised but unusable though, rather strange.